# Ask about possibilty to use Digispark Pro as RFID Tag

Tags: integrated-circuit, programming, tag

I have read this article that explain how to use Attiny85 as RFID tag.
[Using an AVR as an RFID tag](http://scanlime.org/2008/09/using-an-avr-as-an-rfid-tag/)

Is it possible to program Digispark Pro and use it as RFID tag??

Answer (score 1):

An RFID tag is just a MCU with a coil, outputting over a fixed frequency carrier wave. Some are passive, i.e. they harvest energy over the coil, while others are Active, with their own power source. There is nothing special about the RFID spec. So yes, it should provided with the right coil and programming.